# AttributeError: Class1 object has no attribute 'class2_set' with ManyToMany Field Django

Tags: django, manytomanyfield, django-tests

Model :

```
class Groupe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    autoAddingMail = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)
    association = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        limit_choices_to={'role': 'ASSOCIATION'},
        null=False,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='association'
    )
    students = models.ManyToManyField(
        User,
        limit_choices_to={'role': 'STUDENT'},
        related_name='students'
    )
    events = models.ManyToManyField(
        Event
    )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("name","association")

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name','association']

    def __str__(self):
        """ Return string representation of our user """
        return self.name
```

Unit test :

`groupe = event.groupe_set.get(name="name",association=association)` <= works fine

`groupe = student.groupe_set.get(name="name",association=association)` <= doesn't work

The error :
`AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'groupe_set'`

I don't get why student doesn't have the attribute groupe_set but event have it

I have read the documentation about ManyToMany Fields but I didn't find answers.

Comment: you have set related_name which specifies the name of the reverse relation
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

> groupe = student.groupe_set.get(name="name",association=association)

I had to use :

> groupe = student.students.get(name="name",association=association)

Because of the related_name.
Thanks to @iklinac for his comment.